# Problem with using xpath in on osm file with libxml2 library in c programe

Tags: c, xml, xpath, libxml2

I'm working on XML file (in particula .osm file) with libxml2 and C language.

This is my XML source (not all but just a piece):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.3.3 (17077 thorn-02.openstreetmap.org)" copyright="OpenStreetMap and contributors" attribution="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" license="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1-0/">
 <bounds minlat="48.8416800" minlon="2.3422900" maxlat="48.8430200" maxlon="2.3456400"/>
 <node id="470136" visible="true" version="7" changeset="4816046" timestamp="2010-05-26T19:25:12Z" user="Mawie" uid="150619" lat="48.8443318" lon="2.3420496">
  <tag k="highway" v="traffic_signals"/>
 </node>
 <node id="25033471" visible="true" version="2" changeset="4486432" timestamp="2010-04-21T13:24:55Z" user="Mawie" uid="150619" lat="48.8426543" lon="2.3443756"/>
 <node id="25033470" visible="true" version="3" changeset="4486432" timestamp="2010-04-21T13:24:55Z" user="Mawie" uid="150619" lat="48.8424525" lon="2.3442707"/>
 <node id="25033533" visible="true" version="4" changeset="4063350" timestamp="2010-03-07T17:01:22Z" user="lapinos03" uid="33634" lat="48.8427422" lon="2.3413616"/>
 <node id="1110453124" visible="true" version="3" changeset="19056700" timestamp="2013-11-22T15:46:42Z" user="Élie Gouzien" uid="1811864" lat="48.8419798" lon="2.3444183">
  <tag k="name" v="Aquarium"/>
 </node>
 <node id="1750369420" visible="true" version="2" changeset="19056700" timestamp="2013-11-22T15:46:42Z" user="Élie Gouzien" uid="1811864" lat="48.8422145" lon="2.3455341">
  <tag k="amenity" v="theatre"/>
  <tag k="name" v="Nouveau théâtre"/>
 </node>
.
.
.
<way id="4217107" visible="true" version="5" changeset="4768013" timestamp="2010-05-21T17:45:57Z" user="Esperanza36" uid="83557">
  <nd ref="25033470"/>
  <nd ref="25033531"/>
  <tag k="cycleway" v="opposite"/>
  <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
  <tag k="maxspeed" v="30"/>
  <tag k="name" v="Rue Louis Thuillier"/>
  <tag k="oneway" v="yes"/>
 </way>
.
.
.
</osm>
```

...

and i'm trying to retreive the node "way" using xpath expression, the specific way node i want to get is those with attribute tag k = "highway".

here is my xpath expression, xmlChar *xpath = (xmlChar*) (".//way/*[@k="highway"]/..");

i've tested on this website https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-outputbut and it give me the result that i want.

```
Element='<way changeset="4768013"
     id="4217107"
     timestamp="2010-05-21T17:45:57Z"
     uid="83557"
     user="Esperanza36"
     version="5"
     visible="true">
  <nd ref="25033470"/>
  <nd ref="25033531"/>
  <tag k="cycleway" v="opposite"/>
  <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
  <tag k="maxspeed" v="30"/>
  <tag k="name" v="Rue Louis Thuillier"/>
  <tag k="oneway" v="yes"/>
 </way>'
.
.
.
```

...

so it means my xpath expression is correct, but the problem is when i try to use it on my c programme it give me "No result".

I've do some research on internet but there is just so few article about it, someone say that's because the namespacce problem but the osm file that i parsed don't have any namespace atrribute, can someone help me out about it? Thanks a lot!

Here is the code **test.c** i use for test, and the test file you can find on : https://github.com/cblberlin/4M016_Projet/blob/master/test/5eme_petit.osm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/xpath.h>

xmlDocPtr
getdoc (char *docname) {
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    doc = xmlParseFile(docname);
    
    if (doc == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Document not parsed successfully. \n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return doc;
}

xmlXPathObjectPtr getnodeset (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlChar *xpath)
{

    xmlXPathContextPtr context;
    xmlXPathObjectPtr result;

    context = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);

    if (context == NULL) {
        printf("Error in xmlXPathNewContext\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    result = xmlXPathEvalExpression(xpath, context);
    xmlXPathFreeContext(context);

    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("Error in xmlXPathEvalExpression\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if(xmlXPathNodeSetIsEmpty(result->nodesetval)){
        xmlXPathFreeObject(result);
                printf("No result\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return result;
}


int
main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char *docname;
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlChar *xpath = (xmlChar*) (".//way/*[@k=\"highway\"]/..");
    xmlNodeSetPtr nodeset;
    xmlXPathObjectPtr result;
    int i;
    xmlChar *keyword;
        
    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("Usage: %s docname\n", argv[0]);
        return(0);
    }

    docname = argv[1];
    doc = getdoc(docname);
    result = getnodeset (doc, xpath);
    if (result) {
        nodeset = result->nodesetval;
        for (i=0; i < nodeset->nodeNr; i++) {
            keyword = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, nodeset->nodeTab[i]->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
        printf("keyword: %s\n", keyword);
        xmlFree(keyword);
        }
        xmlXPathFreeObject (result);
    }
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    xmlCleanupParser();
    return (1);
}
```

and with

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -I/include/libxml test.c -o test.exe -lm -lxml2
```

this command to compile, and

```
./test.exe 5eme_petit.osm
```

to execute it, i get

```
No result
```

updated:
With the response of **Yitzhak Khabinsky**, xpath = /osm/way[tag/@k='highway'], i got this as result

```
keyword: 
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
 
keyword: 
  
  
  
  
  
 
keyword: 
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
 
keyword: 
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
 
keyword: 
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
 
keyword: 
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
 
keyword: 
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
 
keyword: 
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
 
keyword: 
  
  
  
  
  
 
keyword: 
  
  
  
  
  
 
keyword: 
  
  
  
  
  
 
keyword: 
  
  
  
  
  
 
keyword: 
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
 
keyword:
```

it's not what i expected for but it's a huge improve compare with nothing. And also i tested it online, it show me the same result as i used my previous declaration.

update:

I tested it online with /osm/way[tag/@k='highway']/nd[@ref], it do give me what i want but i just don't how to print it on the terminal, which function should i use to retreive the information?

result online is below

```
Element='<nd ref="25033470"/>'

Element='<nd ref="25033531"/>'

Element='<nd ref="25033471"/>'

Element='<nd ref="25033484"/>'

Element='<nd ref="25033485"/>'

Element='<nd ref="25033531"/>'

Element='<nd ref="25033533"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1141486778"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1141486770"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1141486793"/>'

Element='<nd ref="470136"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1141486787"/>'

Element='<nd ref="25033343"/>'

Element='<nd ref="25033531"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1141486768"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1141486743"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1141486757"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1141486778"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1142802914"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1141486745"/>'

Element='<nd ref="15641131"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380021"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380025"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380026"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380029"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380028"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380027"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380024"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380020"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380019"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380015"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380016"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380018"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380021"/>'

Element='<nd ref="15641131"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1142802901"/>'

Element='<nd ref="277054805"/>'

Element='<nd ref="25033470"/>'

Element='<nd ref="25033471"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380022"/>'

Element='<nd ref="2450344040"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380030"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380033"/>'

Element='<nd ref="2450344042"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380031"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380023"/>'

Element='<nd ref="2450344039"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380017"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380012"/>'

Element='<nd ref="2450344037"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380014"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380022"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380032"/>'

Element='<nd ref="2450344041"/>'

Element='<nd ref="2450344040"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380025"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380035"/>'

Element='<nd ref="2450344043"/>'

Element='<nd ref="2450344042"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380028"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380013"/>'

Element='<nd ref="2450344038"/>'

Element='<nd ref="2450344039"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380020"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380009"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380010"/>'

Element='<nd ref="2450344037"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380016"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380036"/>'

Element='<nd ref="2450344043"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380034"/>'

Element='<nd ref="2450344038"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380008"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380010"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380011"/>'

Element='<nd ref="2450344041"/>'

Element='<nd ref="1750380036"/>'

Element='<nd ref="25033471"/>'

Element='<nd ref="25033340"/>'
```

solved:
i found this example which give me hint to solve it,

code as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/xpath.h>

xmlDocPtr
getdoc (char *docname) {
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    doc = xmlParseFile(docname);
    
    if (doc == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Document not parsed successfully. \n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return doc;
}

xmlXPathObjectPtr getnodeset (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlChar *xpath)
{

    xmlXPathContextPtr context;
    xmlXPathObjectPtr result;

    context = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);

    if (context == NULL) {
        printf("Error in xmlXPathNewContext\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    result = xmlXPathEvalExpression(xpath, context);
    xmlXPathFreeContext(context);

    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("Error in xmlXPathEvalExpression\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if(xmlXPathNodeSetIsEmpty(result->nodesetval)){
        xmlXPathFreeObject(result);
                printf("No result\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return result;
}




int
main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char *docname;
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlChar *xpath = (xmlChar*) ("/osm/way[tag/@k='highway']");
    xmlNodeSetPtr nodeset;
    xmlXPathObjectPtr result;
    int i;
    xmlChar *keyword;
        
    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("Usage: %s docname\n", argv[0]);
        return(0);
    }

    docname = argv[1];
    doc = getdoc(docname);
    result = getnodeset (doc, xpath);
    if (result) {
        nodeset = result->nodesetval;
        for (i=0; i < nodeset->nodeNr; i++) {
            printf("way id: %s\n", xmlGetProp( nodeset->nodeTab[i], BAD_CAST "id" ));
            xmlNodePtr cur = nodeset->nodeTab[i]->children;
            while(cur != NULL)
            {
                if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) 
                {   
                    //printf("\t%s", cur->name);
                    if (!(xmlStrcmp(cur->name, BAD_CAST "nd")))
                    {
                        keyword = xmlGetProp(cur, BAD_CAST "ref");
                        printf("\tref is %s\n", keyword);
                    }
                    //cur = cur->next;
                }
                cur = cur->next;
            }
            //keyword = xmlGetProp(nodeset->nodeTab[i], BAD_CAST "ref");
            //printf("keyword: %s\n", keyword);
            //xmlFree(keyword);
        }
        xmlXPathFreeObject (result);
    }
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    xmlCleanupParser();
    return (1);
}
```

which give me result as

```
$ ./test.exe 5eme_petit.osm 
way id: 4217107
    ref is 25033470
    ref is 25033531
way id: 4217181
    ref is 25033471
    ref is 25033484
    ref is 25033485
way id: 4217066
    ref is 25033531
    ref is 25033533
way id: 98668365
    ref is 1141486778
    ref is 1141486770
    ref is 1141486793
way id: 68907088
    ref is 470136
    ref is 1141486787
    ref is 25033343
    ref is 25033531
    ref is 1141486768
    ref is 1141486743
    ref is 1141486757
    ref is 1141486778
    ref is 1142802914
    ref is 1141486745
    ref is 15641131
way id: 163320090
    ref is 1750380021
    ref is 1750380025
    ref is 1750380026
    ref is 1750380029
    ref is 1750380028
    ref is 1750380027
    ref is 1750380024
    ref is 1750380020
    ref is 1750380019
    ref is 1750380015
    ref is 1750380016
    ref is 1750380018
    ref is 1750380021
way id: 197695748
    ref is 15641131
    ref is 1142802901
    ref is 277054805
    ref is 25033470
    ref is 25033471
way id: 163320099
    ref is 1750380022
    ref is 2450344040
    ref is 1750380030
    ref is 1750380033
    ref is 2450344042
    ref is 1750380031
    ref is 1750380023
    ref is 2450344039
    ref is 1750380017
    ref is 1750380012
    ref is 2450344037
    ref is 1750380014
    ref is 1750380022
way id: 163320094
    ref is 1750380032
    ref is 2450344041
    ref is 2450344040
    ref is 1750380025
way id: 163320091
    ref is 1750380035
    ref is 2450344043
    ref is 2450344042
    ref is 1750380028
way id: 163320096
    ref is 1750380013
    ref is 2450344038
    ref is 2450344039
    ref is 1750380020
way id: 163320095
    ref is 1750380009
    ref is 1750380010
    ref is 2450344037
    ref is 1750380016
way id: 163320097
    ref is 1750380036
    ref is 2450344043
    ref is 1750380034
    ref is 2450344038
    ref is 1750380008
    ref is 1750380010
    ref is 1750380011
    ref is 2450344041
    ref is 1750380036
way id: 241561441
    ref is 25033471
    ref is 25033340
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following XPath expression:

```
/osm/way[tag/@k='highway']
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response man, it finally show me something even it's just repeat the word keyword, i guess i have to edit my xpath based on your anwer!

Comment: i guess your xpath expression dit get the information, but how can i get the inside information using libxml2? I need the ref information to create the adjacency list for my dijkstra algorithm